# "attempted to retain deallocated object" in circular reference

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a program that tracks precious metals prices.

A TransactionDTO has an unowned reference to an AssetDTO

AssetDTO Snippet:

```
public class AssetDTO: Equatable {
var name: String!
var transactions = [TransactionDTO]()
```

TransactionDTO Snippet:

```
unowned var asset: AssetDTO

init(asset:AssetDTO, type:Constants.TransactionType) {
    self.asset = asset
    self.type = type
    self.date = Date()
}
```

In a UI controller class, I iterate over the transactions in a table, and show the related metal (gold, silver, etc). In my viewDidLoad, to demonstrate the error, i have the following code

```
    var txs = [TransactionDTO]()
    for asset in assetManager.findAllMetals() {
        for tx in asset.transactions {
            txs.append(tx)
            print("the asset name for this is \(tx.asset.name)")
        }
    }

    for tx in txs {
        print("the asset name for this is \(tx.asset.name)")
    }
```

In the first loop, the name of the asset prints, in the second loop, i get:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_abortRetainUnowned:
0x108d44cc0 <+0>:  leaq   0x3058b(%rip), %rax       ; "attempted to retain deallocated object"
0x108d44cc7 <+7>:  movq   %rax, 0x95f0a(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x108d44cce <+14>: int3   ->  0x108d44ccf <+15>: nop
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `unowned` from

```
    unowned var asset: AssetDTO
```

`unowned` is effectively like `weak`, and presumably nothing else is referencing the asset, so it gets deallocated. However, unlike `weak`, `unowned` does not nil out the variable for you. Hence the error you're getting. If you change it to `weak`, you will probably find it is becoming nil.

Since you're wanting to avoid the circular reference between an asset holding transactions, and each transaction having a reference to the asset, the latter should be declared `weak`.

The problem is then the scope of `assetManager.findAllMetals()`. If nothing holds a reference to the assets it returns, they will be destroyed. Since you have a reference to an array of transactions, the assets to which they refer will be destroyed after the first loop.

The simplest fix is to keep your own reference outside the scope of the first loop. Along the lines of:

```
let allMetails = assetManager.findAllMetals()
var txs = [TransactionDTO]()
for asset in allMetals {
    for tx in asset.transactions {
        txs.append(tx)
        print("the asset name for this is \(tx.asset.name)")
    }
}

for tx in txs {
    print("the asset name for this is \(tx.asset.name)")
}
```

Comment: when i use weak, i get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP) at the second print line. So yes, it is becoming nil.  Im just trying to avoid a memory leak. I just want to get access to the data in the asset, and I don't understand why the state of its availability changes across 2 loop iterations.

Comment: In the first loop, you have a reference to `asset`, that goes out of scope at the end of the loop, and hence `asset` gets released and no longer exists in the second loop. You only need to worry about memory leaks when there is a circular reference (A holds a reference to B and B holds a reference to A), and in that case you should generally use `weak`. In your case, assuming `asset` does not hold a reference to `Transaction`, then you don't need either.

Comment: its a many-to-one relationship.  the AssetDTO has many transactions, and a TransactionDTO has an AssetDTO.  Thats where I have the circular reference. If AssetDTO has an array, I guess it would be the array with the reference, and not the asset.

Comment: In that case I expect the error is with `assetManager.findAllMetals()` going out of scope. Are the assets it is returning held elsewhere or created on the fly? If they're created, they will be getting destroyed after the first loop.

Comment: You are spot-on Michael! Changing the scope of the assets to be a field on the class solved it!! many thanks!!

Comment: Great. I will update my answer to reflect the final understanding.